# AFNetworking Post Request

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking, afnetworking-2

I'm a newbie in obj-c and have been using asihttp for some of my projects. When doing a post request in asihttp its done this way.

```
    ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [request setPostValue:height forKey:@"user[height]"];
    [request setPostValue:weight forKey:@"user[weight]"];
    [request setDelegate:self];
    [request startAsynchronous];
```

How would  go about doing this is AFNetworking with a code example ?
I already got the get Json getrequest working in AFNetworking but this post request is giving me some problems. Thanks for help in advance.

Answer (score 213, accepted):

It's first worth adding (as this answer is still popular 6 years after I initially wrote it...) that the first thing you should consider is whether you should even use AFNetworking. NSURLSession was added in iOS 7 and means you don't need to use AFNetworking in many cases - and one less third party library is always a good thing.

For AFNetworking 3.0:

```
AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];
NSDictionary *params = @{@"user[height]": height,
                         @"user[weight]": weight};
[manager POST:@"https://example.com/myobject" parameters:params progress:nil success:^(NSURLSessionTask *task, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
} failure:^(NSURLSessionTask *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];
```

For AFNetworking 2.0 (and also using the new NSDictionary syntax):

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
NSDictionary *params = @{@"user[height]": height,
                         @"user[weight]": weight};
[manager POST:@"https://example.com/myobject" parameters:params success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];
```

If you are stuck using AFNetworking 1.0, you need to do it this way:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://example.com/"];
AFHTTPClient *httpClient = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:url];

NSDictionary *params = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                        height, @"user[height]",
                        weight, @"user[weight]",
                        nil];
[httpClient postPath:@"/myobject" parameters:params success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSString *responseStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseObject encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"Request Successful, response '%@'", responseStr);
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"[HTTPClient Error]: %@", error.localizedDescription);
}];
```

Comment: Thank you very much Joseph it worked very well. I just had a question after I alloc the httpClient I release it after creating the request, I dont seem to have any crashes and seems to work well. I just wanted to confirm that that is the correct spot to release it. Thank you very much again. Kind Regards

Comment: Yes, that would works. The AFHTTPClient is really intended to be kept around and used again if you make another request, but releasing it straight after the 'requestWithMethod:' call is acceptable.

Comment: Hi Joseph, I finally got it working with a json response and I set up another question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7630289/afnetworking-post-request-with-json-feedback to really know whether I am doing it right. Thanks so much sorry to bother.

Comment: By now it seems there's no more "operationWithRequest:completion" method for AFHTTPRequestOperation... just use "initWithRequest" and then "setCompletionBlockWithSuccess".

Comment: @Rakesh It's difficult to properly answer a question like that in comments - can I suggest you open a new question please?

Comment: @JosephH I done this : checkout : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20194654/cookie-with-afnetwroking-2-0

Comment: I have a xml content that need to attach in HTTPBody of request, How can I do to add to post request.

Comment: Please, for AFNetworking 3.0 is it the same as AFNetworking 2.0?

Comment: @Llg Very slightly different, but not much. I added an example for 3.0 to my post.

Answer (score 32):

```
NSDictionary *params = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                       height, @"user[height]",
                       weight, @"user[weight]",
                       nil];

AFHTTPClient *client = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:
                                             [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://localhost:8080/"]];

[client postPath:@"/mypage.php" parameters:params success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
     NSString *text = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseObject encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
     NSLog(@"Response: %@", text);
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
     NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);
}];
```

Answer (score 12):

Here is a simple AFNetworking POST I'm using. To get up and running after
reading the AFNetworking doc, wkiki, ref, etc, I learned a lot by
following http://nsscreencast.com/episodes/6-afnetworking and understanding
the associated code sample on github.

```
 // Add this to the class you're working with - (id)init {}
    _netInst = [MyApiClient sharedAFNetworkInstance];

  // build the dictionary that AFNetworkng converts to a json object on the next line
  //  params = {"user":{"email":emailAddress,"password":password}};
  NSDictionary *parameters =[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                             userName, @"email", password, @"password", nil];
  NSDictionary *params =[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                         parameters, @"user", nil];

   [_netInst postPath: @"users/login.json" parameters:params
      success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id jsonResponse) {
        NSLog (@"SUCCESS");

        // jsonResponse = {"user":{"accessId":1234,"securityKey":"abc123"}};
        _accessId = [jsonResponse valueForKeyPath:@"user.accessid"];
        _securityKey = [jsonResponse valueForKeyPath:@"user.securitykey"];

        return SUCCESS;
      }
      failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"FAILED");

        // handle failure

        return error;
      }
   ];
```

Comment: Is the responseObject automatically parsed into JSON?

Answer (score 3):

**For AFNetworking 4**

```
AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];
NSDictionary *params = @{@"user[height]": height,
                         @"user[weight]": weight};
[manager POST:@"https://example.com/myobject" parameters:params headers:nil progress:nil success:^(NSURLSessionTask *task, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
} failure:^(NSURLSessionTask *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];
```

Answer (score 2):

```
    AFHTTPClient * Client = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://urlname"]];
    NSDictionary * parameters = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    parameters = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                 height, @"user[height]",
                        weight, @"user[weight]",
                  nil]; 

    [Client setParameterEncoding:AFJSONParameterEncoding];
    [Client postPath:@"users/login.json" parameters:parameters success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"operation hasAcceptableStatusCode: %d", [operation.response statusCode]);

    NSLog(@"response string: %@ ", operation.responseString);

    NSDictionary *jsonResponseDict = [operation.responseString JSONValue];
        if ([[jsonResponseDict objectForKey:@"responseBody"] isKindOfClass:[NSMutableDictionary class]]) {
            NSMutableDictionary *responseBody =  [jsonResponseDict objectForKey:@"responseBody"];
           //get the response here


    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

        NSLog(@"error: %@", operation.responseString);
        NSLog(@"%d",operation.response.statusCode);

    }];
```

Hope this works.

Answer (score 1):

Here an example with **Swift 3.0**

```
let manager = AFHTTPSessionManager(sessionConfiguration: URLSessionConfiguration.default)
manager.requestSerializer = AFJSONRequestSerializer()
manager.requestSerializer.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
manager.requestSerializer.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")

if authenticated {
    if let user = UserDAO.currentUser() {
        manager.requestSerializer.setValue("Authorization", forHTTPHeaderField: user.headerForAuthentication())
    }
}

manager.post(url, parameters: parameters, progress: nil, success: { (task: URLSessionDataTask, responseObject: Any?) in 
    if var jsonResponse = responseObject as? [String: AnyObject] {
        // here read response
    }
}) { (task: URLSessionDataTask?, error: Error) in
    print("POST fails with error \(error)")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
[SVProgressHUD setDefaultMaskType:SVProgressHUDMaskTypeGradient];
[SVProgressHUD show];

NSDictionary *dictParam =@{@"user_id":@"31"};// Add perameter

NSString *URLString =@"your url string";

AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];
[manager setResponseSerializer:[AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer]];
[manager.requestSerializer setValue:strGlobalLoginToken forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];//strGlobalLoginToken is your login token
//         [manager.requestSerializer setValue:setHeaderEnv forHTTPHeaderField:@"Env"];
manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObjects:@"application/json", @"text/json", @"text/javascript",@"text/html",@"text/plain",@"application/rss+xml", nil];
[manager POST:URLString parameters:dictParam progress:nil success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nonnull task, id  _Nullable responseObject)
 {

     NSDictionary *response = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseObject options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:nil];

     NSLog(@"Response DICT:%@",response);

     if ([[[[response objectForKey:@"response"] objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"status"] isEqualToString:@"true"])
     {

         for (NSMutableDictionary *dicAll in [[[response objectForKey:@"response"]objectAtIndex:0]objectForKey:@"plans"])
         {
             [yourNsmutableArray addObject:[dicAll mutableCopy]];
         }
         //yourNsmutableArray Nsmutablearray  alloction in view didload

         NSLog(@"yourNsmutableArray  %@",yourNsmutableArray);
     }
     else
     {
         NSLog(@"False");
     }

     [SVProgressHUD dismiss];

 } failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask  *_Nullable task, NSError  *_Nonnull error)
 {
     NSLog(@"RESPONSE STRING:%@",task.response);
     NSLog(@"error userInfo:%@",error.userInfo);

     NSString *errResponse = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:(NSData *)error.userInfo[AFNetworkingOperationFailingURLResponseDataErrorKey] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
     NSLog(@"URLString :--->>   %@ Error********* %@",URLString,errResponse);

     [SVProgressHUD dismiss];

 }];
```

Answer (score 0):

For AFNetworking 3.0 and Swift. Maybe we can use like this:

```
let configutation = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
manager = AFHTTPSessionManager(sessionConfiguration: configutation)

let urlString = "url"
manager.POST(urlString, parameters: [params here], progress: nil, success: { (dataTask: NSURLSessionDataTask, response: AnyObject?) -> Void in
        print(dataTask)
        print(response)
        }) { (dataTask: NSURLSessionDataTask?, error: NSError) -> Void in
        print(error)
}
```

Hope this will help other find answer like me!

Answer (score 0):

For AFNetworking **3.0** (**iOS9 or greter**)

```
 NSString *strURL = @"https://exampleWeb.com/webserviceOBJ";
    NSDictionary *dictParamiters = @{@"user[height]": height,@"user[weight]": weight};

    NSString *aStrParams = [self getFormDataStringWithDictParams:dictParamiters];

    NSData *aData = [aStrParams dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSMutableURLRequest *aRequest = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc]initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strURL]];
    [aRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [aRequest setHTTPBody:aData];

    NSURLSessionConfiguration *configuration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
    NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:configuration delegate:nil delegateQueue:nil];
    [aRequest setHTTPBody:aData];

    NSURLSessionDataTask *postDataTask = [session dataTaskWithRequest:aRequest completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
        //
        if (error ==nil) {
            NSString *aStr = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
            NSLog(@"ResponseString:%@",aStr);
            NSMutableDictionary *aMutDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    completionBlock(aMutDict);

                NSLog(@"responce:%@",aMutDict)

            });
        }
        else
        {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                NSLog(@"error:%@",error.locali)
            });
        }
    }];

    [postDataTask resume];
```

and Add

```
-(NSString *)getFormDataStringWithDictParams:(NSDictionary *)aDict
{
    NSMutableString *aMutStr = [[NSMutableString alloc]initWithString:@""];
    for (NSString *aKey in aDict.allKeys) {
        [aMutStr appendFormat:@"%@=%@&",aKey,aDict[aKey]];
    }
    NSString *aStrParam;
    if (aMutStr.length>2) {
        aStrParam = [aMutStr substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, aMutStr.length-1)];

    }
    else
        aStrParam = @"";

    return aStrParam;
}
```

Comment: That code doesn't use AFNetworking at all. It's just an example of how to use NSURLSession.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"url"];


AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];
NSDictionary *params = @{@"prefix":@"param",@"prefix":@"param",@"prefix":@"param"};
[manager POST:URL.absoluteString parameters:params progress:nil success:^(NSURLSessionTask *task, id responseObject) {
    self.arrayFromPost = [responseObject objectForKey:@"data"];
    // values in foreach loop


    NSLog(@"POst send: %@",_arrayFromPost);
} failure:^(NSURLSessionTask *operation, NSError *error) {


    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSMutableDictionary *dictParam = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
[dictParam setValue:@"VALUE_NAME" forKey:@"KEY_NAME"]; //set parameters like id, name, date, product_name etc

if ([[AppDelegate instance] checkInternetConnection]) {
    NSError *error;
    NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dictParam options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&error];                                             

    if (jsonData) {
        NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"Api Url"]
                                                               cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData
                                                           timeoutInterval:30.0f];
        [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

        [request setHTTPBody:jsonData];
        [request setValue:ACCESS_TOKEN forHTTPHeaderField:@"TOKEN"];

        AFHTTPRequestOperation *op = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
        op.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
        op.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObjects:@"text/plain",@"text/html",@"application/json", nil];

        [op setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
         arrayList = [responseObject valueForKey:@"data"];
         [_tblView reloadData];
         } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
         //show failure alert
         }];
        [op start];
    }
} else {
    [UIAlertView infoAlertWithMessage:NO_INTERNET_AVAIL andTitle:APP_NAME];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// For Image with parameter /// AFMultipartFormData

NSDictionary *dictParam =@{@"user_id":strGlobalUserId,@"name":[dictParameter objectForKey:@"Name"],@"contact":[dictParameter objectForKey:@"Contact Number"]};

AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [[AFHTTPSessionManager alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:webServiceUrl]];
[manager.requestSerializer setValue:strGlobalLoginToken forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];
manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObjects:@"application/json", @"text/json", @"text/javascript",@"text/html",@"text/plain",@"application/rss+xml", nil];
[manager POST:@"update_profile" parameters:dictParam constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData>  _Nonnull formData) {
    if (Imagedata.length>0) {
        [formData appendPartWithFileData:Imagedata name:@"profile_pic" fileName:@"photo.jpg" mimeType:@"image/jpeg"];
    }
} progress:nil
      success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nonnull task, id  _Nullable responseObject)
 {
     NSLog(@"update_profile %@", responseObject);

     if ([[[[responseObject objectForKey:@"response"] objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"status"] isEqualToString:@"true"])
     {
         [self presentViewController:[global SimpleAlertviewcontroller:@"" Body:[[[responseObject objectForKey:@"response"] objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"response_msg"] handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {
             [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];

         }] animated:YES completion:nil];


     }
     else
     {
         [self presentViewController:[global SimpleAlertviewcontroller:@"" Body:[[[responseObject objectForKey:@"response"] objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"response_msg"] handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {
         }] animated:YES completion:nil];

     }
     [SVProgressHUD dismiss];

 } failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask  *_Nullable task, NSError  *_Nonnull error)
 {
     [SVProgressHUD dismiss];
 }];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
please try below answer.

+(void)callAFWSPost:(NSDictionary *)dict withURL:(NSString *)strUrl 
withBlock:(dictionary)block
{
AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [[AFHTTPSessionManager alloc]initWithSessionConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration]];
[manager.requestSerializer setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
manager.requestSerializer = [AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer];
manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObjects:@"application/json", @"text/json", @"text/javascript",@"text/html", nil];
[manager POST:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@",WebserviceUrl,strUrl] parameters:dict progress:nil success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nonnull task, id  _Nullable responseObject)
 {
     if (!responseObject)
     {
         NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
         [dict setObject:ServerResponceError forKey:@"error"];
         block(responseObject);
         return ;
     }
     else if ([responseObject isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
         block(responseObject);
         return ;
     }
 }
      failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nullable task, NSError * _Nonnull error)
 {
     NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
     [dict setObject:ServerResponceError forKey:@"error"];
     block(dict);
 }];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

for login screen;

```
NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
dict = [NSMutableDictionary 

dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:_usernametf.text, @"username",_passwordtf.text, @"password", nil];
    AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];
    manager.requestSerializer = [AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer];

[manager POST:@"enter your url" parameters:dict progress:nil success:^(NSURLSessionTask *task, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"%@", responseObject);

}
      failure:^(NSURLSessionTask *operation, NSError *error) {
          NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
      }];
```

}

Answer (score -1):

Using AFNetworking 3.0, you should write:

```
NSString *strURL = @"https://exampleWeb.com/webserviceOBJ";
NSURL * urlStr = [NSURL URLWithString:strURL];

NSDictionary *dictParameters = @{@"user[height]": height,@"user[weight]": weight};

AFHTTPSessionManager * manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];


[manager POST:url.absoluteString parameters:dictParameters success:^(NSURLSessionTask *task, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"PLIST: %@", responseObject);
   
} failure:^(NSURLSessionTask *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    
}];
```

Comment: This looks good, but i think OP was looking for how to send a POST request.