# How to convert NSURLConnection to AFNetworking?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, afnetworking, afnetworking-2

i want to convert this code to AFNetworking but i have a error. i used

> [AFNetworking POST to REST webservice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9927945/afnetworking-post-to-rest-webservice) this code.

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];

NSString *latest_url = @"url_string";

[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:latest_url]];  

[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setValue:useragent_string forHTTPHeaderField:@"User-Agent"];
[request setValue:host_string forHTTPHeaderField:@"Host"];
[request setValue:@"keep-alive" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Connection"];
[request setValue:@"keep-alive" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Proxy-Connection"];
[request setTimeoutInterval:30.0];
[request setHTTPBody:postData];   

NSError *errorx = nil;

NSData *response = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:&errorx];

NSString *json_string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:response encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSData *jsonData = [json_string dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSError *jsonerror;

NSData *get_data_from_request = [ourdelegate do_request:request_url post_array:request_post_array debug:istekdebug];

NSArray *statuses =[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData: jsonData options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error: &jsonerror];
```

How to convert this code to AFNetworking?

Comment: Why don't you post the issue you are having when you converted to the code `AFNetwork`, now it looks like you are expecting us to code it for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using post request, here's what you can do with AFHTTPSessionManager. You can also call AFHTTPSessionManager Get method with block invocation.

```
NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL URLWithString:BaseURLString];
NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"Host": host_string};

AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [[AFHTTPSessionManager alloc] initWithBaseURL:baseURL];
manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];


[manager POST:@"yourFile.php" parameters:parameters success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id responseObject) {
         NSLog("handle succes");
    } failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, NSError *error) {
         NSLog("handle error %@",[error localizedDescription]);
}];
```

Have fun :)

Answer (score 0):

Since you aren't being specific with the error like rckoenes mentioned above.......

Why don't you just go get [PAW](https://luckymarmot.com/paw) from LuckyMarmot

It helps you formulate REST api calls and will translate the request into AFNetworking for you.  Phenomenal tool for only $19.99.  Worth every penny.

Comment: Superb tool !! Liked it.