# POST and PUT request AFNetworking

Tags: ios, rest, post, put, afnetworking

I'm trying to do a call to a server. The GET call is working great and returns the correct json, but when I try to do a PUT or a POST, the server returns an error.

I set the server to receive the next messages:

```
method POST
curl -X POST -d "number=NUMBER&name=NAME&lat=32.5713&lon=60.3926"  http://server.com/users/

method PUT
curl -X PUT -d "number=USER&name=NAME6&lat=-34.5552&lon=32.3333"  http://server.com/users/
```

How can I call to the server with these two methods?

Comment: What does this have to do with AFNetworking, exactly? Are you using AFN to make these requests? CAn you post code examples of how you're using AFN?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would create a APIClient class for all requests instead of creating a new client every time i make a request.

See : https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/tree/master/Example/Classes
AFTwitterAPIClient.h & AFTwitterAPIClient.m

but based on your question.
I believe the code will look something like this. (Code was not tested)

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://server.com"];
AFHTTPClient *client = [[AFHTTPClient alloc]initWithBaseURL:url];

//depending on what kind of response you expect.. change it if you expect XML 
[client registerHTTPOperationClass:[AFJSONRequestOperation class]];

NSDictionary *params = [[NSDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:
                        @"NUMBER",@"number", 
                        @"NAME",@"name",
                         @"32.5713",@"lat",
                         @"60.3926",@"lon", 
                        nil];
[client putPath:@"users" parameters:params success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"success");
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"failure");
}];
```

As for the post request.. just use postPath instead of putPath and it'll work fine. :)

Hope I've helped.

Answer (score 1):

Since there is no associated code, I assume you use `getPath:parameters:success:failure:` or no `parameters` sent with *POST* reqd which might be required by your *server/API*.

```
postPath:parameters:success:failure:
putPath:parameters:success:failure:
```

Also refer [AFNetworking Post Request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7623275/afnetworking-post-request) for sample code with POST with AFnetworking