# How to make a PUT HTTP request in ios sdk?

Tags: ios, http, nsurlconnection, nsurlrequest, put

In my application I need to make a **PUT** type request. I have followed the below steps

```
NSString *path = @"http://hostname/api/Account/VerifyUser?applicationToken=72B648C6-B2B7-45ED-BA23-2E8AAA187D2C&emailID=xxx@gmail.com&password=aaaaa";
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:
                                [NSURL URLWithString:path]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"PUT"];
[request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", string.length] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setHTTPBody:[string dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

For POST and GET I am getting correct output.

I have searched a lot but i am not getting any solution.Please suggest me any possible solution .

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you use `AFNetworking` library, you can use `PUT`. http://stackoverflow.com/a/11475108/1679187

Comment: Is it not Possible to do PUT in NSMutableURLRequest???

Comment: May be but I didn't tried. :)

Comment: ok thanks.i will try on AFNetworking.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

For xml request body

```
    Set [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8;application/form-data" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

OR
```

For json request body

```
    Set [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8;application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
```