# AFNetworking POST and get Data back

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, post, afnetworking

in my Iphone app i use AFNetworking to POST some data to a webservice and get some data back...

Here is my example, i always get "false" back as response, what i am doing wrong?

```
NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://myPath/Iphone/method"];


    AFHTTPClient *httpClient = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:baseURL];
    [httpClient defaultValueForHeader:@"Accept"];

    NSDictionary *params = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                            [udid copy], @"uuid",
                            nil];


    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [httpClient requestWithMethod:@"POST" path:@"http://myPath/Iphone/method" parameters:params];


    AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];


    [httpClient registerHTTPOperationClass:[AFXMLRequestOperation class]];


    [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        response = [operation responseString];
        NSLog(@"response: %@",response);
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"error: %@", [operation error]);
    }];


    [operation start];
```

EDIT: the method i call in the Url returns a string  (no the string is not false)

---

```
  [HttpPost]
        public bool checkIphone(string uuid)
        {
           IDictionary<string,object> check  = Request.Properties;

           uuid = check["uuid"].ToString();

           //do anything with the uuid

           if (1<0)
           {
               return true;
           }
           else
           {
               return false;
           }

        }
```

this method i am calling with my iphone and normaly it should return xml or?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7623275/afnetworking-post-request?lq=1

Comment: i already read this but it does not helped me

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using a complicated way of building the operation, but it will work.
But it should work, the thing you are missing is assign the XMLparser.
In the documentation of [AFXMLRequestOperation](http://afnetworking.org/Documentation/Classes/AFXMLRequestOperation.html) is stated.

```
 NSMutableURLRequest *request = [httpClient requestWithMethod:@"POST" path:@"http://myPath/Iphone/method" parameters:params];

AFXMLRequestOperation *operation = [[AFXMLRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
operation.responseXMLParser = xmlParser; //Here you should assign an instance of NSXMLParser to handle you XML parsing.

[operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    response = [operation responseString];
    NSLog(@"response: %@",response);
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"error: %@", [operation error]);
}];
```

Also there is not need to make the NSURLRequest via the [`AFHTTPClient`](http://afnetworking.org/Documentation/Classes/AFHTTPClient.html), you can easily create one you self or use the [`AFHTTPClient`](http://afnetworking.org/Documentation/Classes/AFHTTPClient.html) to do the creation of the [`AFHTTPRequestOperation`](http://afnetworking.org/Documentation/Classes/AFHTTPRequestOperation.html) for you.

---

To use the AFHTTPClient to just return whatever the server returns :

```
// Don't include the method here
NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://myPath/Iphone/"];

AFHTTPClient *httpClient = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:baseURL];
[httpClient defaultValueForHeader:@"Accept"];

NSDictionary *params = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                        [udid copy], @"uuid",
                        nil];

[httpClient postPath:@"method" parameters:params success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    // reponseObject will hold the data returned by the server.

}failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error retrieving data: %@", error);
}];
```

Comment: i do not use NSXMLParser i use the RaptureXML Parser

Comment: The don't use `AFXMLRequestOperation ` and don't set it as the default class in the `AFHTTPClient` just use a plain `AFHTTPRequestOperation` and pase the `responseObject` to `RaptureXML `

Comment: [httpClient postPath:@"method" params success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {} 
got a problem with this line, what should success stand for here in this case?

Comment: is this right when i want to print the responseObject? 
RXMLElement *rxml = [RXMLElement elementFromXMLFile:responseObject];
        NSLog(@"%@", rxml);

Comment: Sorry can't answer that since i've never used `RXMLElement` but you can do NSLog(@"Response: %@", responseObject);

Comment: hmmm then i get back <66616c73 65>
i should get back true ore false :(

Comment: r u sure that the method should not be in the url?
when i use the method i a webbrowser i also use the full url: http://anypath/Iphone/anymethod

Comment: Yes I'm sure, since the base URL is set on the `AFHTTPClient` and it will append the method to the URL. Looks like the responseObject is a `NSData`. Try this: `NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseObject encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]; NSLog(@"response: %@", responseString);`

Comment: hmmm now i get false back, but no matter what i return in the method i call it is always false...
can nslog print standart xml? because that what i return in the method will be returned as an xml object

Comment: Xml is just text, so if the `NSLog` prints 'false' then the server isn't returning any XML.

Comment: is that ok ? [udid copy], @"uuid",

Comment: you saved me!! I realized i have to put the key after its value from your example. Thanks! :'( and :)

Answer (score -1):

Do you have a typo here? `[udid copy], @"uuid",`

Comment: typo? i thought that just makes a copy of the variable

Comment: udid is a NSString with the uuid from the Iphone