# posting data using html in iphone

Tags: iphone, html, http-post

In website the form data is posted using the code below using HTML post request:

```
<div id="requestinfo">
    <form method="post" action="http://abc/form-post.php" id="request_form">
        <input type="hidden" name="field1" value="value1" />
        <input type="hidden" name="field2" value="value2" />
    </form>
</div>
```

How can I do the same in iPhone? `We do not have to use web services.`

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend using [AFNetworking](http://www.afnetworking.com) as a solution for working with HTTP verbs and data.

The `AFHTTPClient` allows you to specify the verb (POST in this case) as well as the parameters to pass.

See: [AFNetworking Post Request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7623275/afnetworking-post-request)