# Best library for http request for iOS apps?

Tags: ios, httprequest, asihttprequest

In my iPhone app, I use ASIHTTPRequest API to make cURL based http requests. I heard that this API is not being maintained and some times it crashes the app. I need to go with some other API where I can make cURL requests to my RESTful API which gives JSON as response.

Can any one suggest me that what is best alternative to ASIHTTPRequest to use in my production  app?

Comment: There are many out there like: [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking).

Answer (score 5):

A really good alternative to ASIHTTPRequest is AFNetworking.
There are good tutorials about how to integrate AFNetworking into your code, below you will find one.
http://www.raywenderlich.com/30445/afnetworking-crash-course

Comment: Can I make url authentication by sending app id, app secret and access token to a RESTful API along with POST data?   I can do

Comment: I can authenticate URL with ASIHTTPRequest as          ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://myhost.com/api/login/format/json"]];
    request.username = @"appidhere";
    request.password = @"appsecret";
    [request setDelegate:self];
    [request setPostValue:@"usernamehere" forKey:@"username];
    [request setPostValue:@"xxxx" forKey:@"pass"];
    [request setPostValue:@"accesstokenvalue" forKey:@"X-API-KEY"];         How can I do this with AFNetworking?

Comment: @satyanarayana Yes you can very well do that with AFNetworking actually they have blocks to help you with. below you will find the link to the answer  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7623275/afnetworking-post-request

Answer (score 2):

You can use [RestKit](http://restkit.org/) its a powerful library that enable u to get ur data from webservice and you can cache it store it local DB and map your json into objects to be used directly ....

Answer (score 0):

Try this one, it really simplifies the HTTP requests, and also comes with handy testing helpers

https://github.com/BadChoice/RVHttp