# Posting data to server to get response

Tags: ios, objective-c, parsing, asihttprequest, asiformdatarequest

I would like send data to server to get response.

I used `ASIFormDataRequest`, `NSMutableURLRequest`, `NSURLSessionConfiguration`.

But i did not get the response.

I tried in these [ways](http://pastie.org/9734291)

[Response](http://pastie.org/9732223)

Please guide me. or suggest me any other ways.

Thank you.

Comment: Have u check and confirm the request u r genrating?

Comment: u mean the service? . I checked server side. its said working fine @iAnurag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best practice is to use AFNetworking :

https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking

There is a lot of data you can find to get guided, for example:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/59255/afnetworking-2-0-tutorial

[AFNetworking Post Request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7623275/afnetworking-post-request)

Comment: i tried this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7623275/afnetworking-post-request. I got this response NSLocalizedDescription=Request failed: internal server error (500)}

Comment: @Babul Try to simulate the request, in order to understand where is the issue (In client, Or in server), by tools like https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/dhc-resthttp-api-client/aejoelaoggembcahagimdiliamlcdmfm?hl=en

Comment: @Babul maybe this is better tool: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/rest-console/cokgbflfommojglbmbpenpphppikmonn?hl=en

Comment: If you are getting 500 from your server, then the server code is not working. This could be the data you are sending isn't what its expecting or a bug in the code on the server side

Comment: @Flexicoder , basically you are right, but maybe the problem is in the way he sends the request from the app, so it is good idea to test it on another client anyway